# Altium Designer board outline and polygon

Tags: pcb-design, altium

Is there a way in Altium to create a rule that will automatically create a recess from board outline when pouring a polygon?

This is tricky to do it with keep out.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is not entirely clear. My interpretation is that you want the polygon to automatically follow the board outline.

If this is the case, create a design rule in the "BoardOutlineClearance" section under the "Manufacturing" heading. Give it a distance like 0.5mm (how far away from the board outline you want your pour to lay).

[image]

Once applied, when drawing a polygon draw the rectangle around the entire board, and only the inside will fill in, leaving a gap of the predetermined width between the pour and the board outline.

[image]

Comment: I had a problem with this rule a moment ago on an arc, i tried again and this works now, don't know why, thanks